# Error when installing ref-napi in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to install the ref-napi library in Node.js on Macbook M1 chip, but I need some help. The steps I did were as follows:

1. Installation of node-gyp `npm install -g node-gyp`.
2. Installation of Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.2.
3. Creation of files **binding.gyp** and **src/binding.cc** which is empty.

```
// binding.gyp
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "binding",
      "sources": [ "src/binding.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Building the node-gyp `node-gyp configure` `node-gyp build` and everything is OK.

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok.

gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
gyp info using node@16.17.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.8 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10"
gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/juanan/Desktop/Paper TFG/hola/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/juanan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/juanan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.17.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/juanan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/juanan/Desktop/Paper TFG/hola',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/binding.node
gyp info ok
```

However, when I run `npm install ref-napi`, the installation fails.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/juanan/Desktop/Paper TFG/hola/node_modules/ref-napi
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.8 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/juanan/Desktop/Paper TFG/hola/node_modules/ref-napi/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/juanan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/juanan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/juanan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/juanan/Desktop/Paper TFG/hola/node_modules/ref-napi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 'TFG/hola/node_modules/node-addon-api'
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 'TFG/hola/node_modules/get-symbol-from-current-process-h/include'
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 'TFG/hola/node_modules/ref-napi/include'
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/juanan/Desktop/Paper TFG/hola/node_modules/ref-napi
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Node version: v16.17.0
node-gyp version: v9.3.0

I don't understand what are the troubles.

Trying to install ref-napi library.